# How to take db backup of mysql db without stopping mysql server

Tags: java, mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

There are APIs dumping data in mysql db and I need to take mysql db backup and run data migration. I need to stop the API server which is preforming insert and might cause data to be inconsistant with the backup. Stopping API server/Mysql server makes our environment to be idle for couple of minutes. Is there any way I can do it without stopping the servers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html) to dump the contents of the database. There are many guides showing how to use it, such as [Dumping Data in SQL Format with mysqldump](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump-sql-format.html).